# Objective C Parsing XML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parsing, xml-parsing

I have an xml like this...

```
    <object>
<list name="subscriptions">
<object>
<string name="id">feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/computerdefense</string>
<string name="title">.:Computer Defense:.</string>
<list name="categories">
<object>
<string name="id">user/14761688561595773457/label/Hacking</string>
<string name="label">Hacking</string>
</object>
</list>
<string name="sortid">7372F971</string>
<number name="firstitemmsec">1240520939961</number>
<string name="htmlUrl">http://www.computerdefense.org</string>
</object>
<object>
<string name="id">feed/http://www.rawseo.com/news/feed/</string>
<string name="title">A blend of programming and seo</string>
<list name="categories">
<object>
<string name="id">user/14761688561595773457/label/Hacking</string>
<string name="label">Hacking</string>
</object>
</list>
<string name="sortid">D6766911</string>
<number name="firstitemmsec">1258495136927</number>
<string name="htmlUrl">http://www.rawseo.com/news</string>
</object>
<object>
<string name="id">feed/http://it-adsense.blogspot.com/atom.xml</string>
<string name="title">AdSense Blog-Italiano</string>
<list name="categories">
<object>
<string name="id">
user/14761688561595773457/label/Seo e Web Marketing
</string>
<string name="label">Seo e Web Marketing</string>
</object>
</list>
<string name="sortid">9FB570ED</string>
<number name="firstitemmsec">1233684720758</number>
<string name="htmlUrl">http://it-adsense.blogspot.com/</string>
</object>
<object>
<string name="id">feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/aextnet</string>
<string name="title">AEXT.NET NET MAGAZINE</string>
<list name="categories"/>
<string name="sortid">70800CFE</string>
<number name="firstitemmsec">1277627346000</number>
<string name="htmlUrl">http://aext.net</string>
</object>
<object>
<string name="id">feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/alessandroscoscia</string>
<string name="title">Alessandro Scoscia</string>
<list name="categories"/>
<string name="sortid">51CB8E6E</string>
<number name="firstitemmsec">1217001547735</number>
<string name="htmlUrl">http://www.alessandroscoscia.it</string>
</object>
<object>
```

Can someone show how can I parse it? 
The text that i need to parse is in body variable

```
NSMutableString *body = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

I need to insert all info in one Array or in a NSDictionary

Answer (score 17):

Best to use an objective-c parsing library.

This article has a good run down of some of the available ones:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Also, this page has full code samples using one of the libraries:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml

Answer (score 0):

i use the [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk) and works perfectly

The only problem are the accented characters, in Brazil we use a lot, now you do not exist for problems with this ...

is permitted by Apple Store submission

[]'s

Answer (score 0):

Follow this answer.May this will help you a lot.
Use XMLReader to parse xml in ios.This file efficiently will parse xml for you in to a easily manageable NSDictionary.

[XML Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16852496/1305001)