# How to parse a xml

Tags: iphone, xml-parsing

i have a content called `[note content];` it holds a xml element with a string `hello world`
the xml element is like

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd\">\n<en-note>hello world </en-note>"
```

I tried NSXMLparser for parsing this,but no luck.how can i parse `[note content];` and separate that string ? Is there any other way for separating this string ?

Comment: @rckoenes ... thank for the link.. I will use this for further dumb questions.... Perhaps it should be your answer...

Comment: duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6990236/468724

Comment: @InderKumarRathore i put NSString *en-note; i get error that is - symbol cannot be a string.so how can i parse this string in xml.

Comment: i have answered your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/9260042/468724

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you can use xml parsing or for the above specific string you can use below code (the other way as you have asked)

```
NSString *str = @"<\?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd\">\n<en-note>hello world </en-note>";
NSArray *arr    = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"<en-note>"];
if ([arr count] == 2) {
    str = [arr objectAtIndex:1];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</en-note>" withString:@""];
}
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Comment: thanks yarrrr,i am ery newble to xml parsing .let me check.

Comment: ,great +10000000 for you great help.Thanks yarrrrr.it works fine .i put  NSString *str = [note content];
    NSArray *arr    = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"<en-note>"];
    if ([arr count] == 2) {
        str = [arr objectAtIndex:1];
        str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</en-note>" withString:@""];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
   noteContent.text = str;

Comment: but try to learn xml parsing.. here is a good library and tutorial http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html

Answer (score 0):

Here, I hope that code helps
http://devmarc.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/devmarc_sample_app_02.11.11-15.22.zip
If you are acquainted with xcode you should know right away what does what :) 
With this code you can parse xml, search for specified terms and also have an activity view, so you know if or how long it is loading. 
The source is from here btw http://devmarc.de/2011/11/02/xcode-ios-tableview-searchbar-xml-parsing-developer-tutorial/