# Objective-C NSXMLParser to NSDirectory

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser

I have this NSXMLParser like so:

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:data];

    NSError *error = nil;

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
    [parser parse];
    //[parser release];

    error = [parser parserError];

    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
    }
```

and I have this method here:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    NSLog(@"Here");
}
```

What I do not understand is how to get the NSDirectory at the end of my first patch of code, the tutorials on the subject and difficult to follow.

Comment: You have to write lots of code in the various `NSXMLParser` delegate methods that deals with the desired elements and extracts the desired data and populates a dictionary or whatever data structures you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store 3 table parsing value in 3 different array in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851737/how-to-store-3-table-parsing-value-in-3-different-array-in-iphone)