# How to handle error from XMLRPC in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xml-rpc

I am working on **Objective-C** and Web Service use **XMLRPC**.

Can you please help me How can I handle below error and display proper error message to user.

**This error received from XMLRPC in string format.**

myString :

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<methodResponse>
<fault>
<value><struct>
<member>
<name>faultCode</name>
<value><int>4</int></value>
</member>
<member>
<name>faultString</name>
<value><string>(u'Sorry, you are not allowed to access this document. Only users with the following access level are currently allowed to do that:\n- Administration/Settings\n\n(Document model: ir.module.module)', None)</string></value>
</member>
</struct></value>
</fault>
</methodResponse>
```

#### Update:

Right now I am using WPXMLRPC
https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/wpxmlrpc

I can't handle this is string

```
(u'Sorry, you are not allowed to access this document. Only users with the following access level are currently allowed to do that:\n- Administration/Settings\n\n(Document model: ir.module.module)', None)
```

My error look like this
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try the following Solutions,

[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16852496/5593725)

[raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/725/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml)

[theappguruz.com](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/xmlparsing-with-nsxmlparser-tutorial)

Comment: Thank you for your link, but I am able to parse xml tag, I have update my answer, please check it and give me replay, If you have any solution.

Comment: Please note that we discourage link-only answers here, and they can be flagged for deletion by the review queue. If you have an answer to give on Stack Overflow, put the information in the answer itself, only adding a link if it is necessary.