# How to convert below XML type into key value pairs and assign it to Labels and Buttons

Tags: objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

I have searched many XML parsing tutorials and Many websites but didn't get help to this time of XML content. 
I just need to parse this XML file and get key/value pairs. So that i can dynamically assign those values to labels/buttons etc.. 
I am using Objective-C

Main intention is to change the screen content when there is a change in the XML file. I am new to this XML parsing stuff. 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScreenContent>
 <content identifier="logo.description" text="current logo"/>
 <content identifier="userid.label" text="User ID"/>
 <content identifier="userid.hint" text=""/>
 <content identifier="password.label" text="Password"/>
 <content identifier="password.hint" text=""/>
 <content identifier="button.login" text="Log in"/>
 <content identifier="forgot.label1" text="Forgot"/>
 <content identifier="forgot.hyperlink1" text="User ID"/>
 <content identifier="forgot.label2" text="or"/>
 <content identifier="forgot.hyperlink2" text="password?"/>
 <content identifier="forgot.description1" text="Forgot User ID"/>
 <content identifier="forgot.description2" text="Forgot Password"/>
 <content identifier="register.registerhyperlabel" text="Don't have a User ID?"/>
 </ScreenContent>`
```

Comment: What language do you plan to use, if any? What is the purpose of parsing this. What sort of output do you want? "Key-value" does not really explain anything.

Comment: I am currently using Objective C. If I give key value as "userid.label".. I need to get "User ID" ('key'  here is 'identifier' of the XML file and 'value'here is the 'text' of the XML file)
Sorry for not mentioning language. I just put a tag as Objective C..

Comment: I understand what key-value are in XML, what you did not mention was if you wish to create "key-val" pairs in a dictionary, tuple, structure etc etc. This following seems good IMO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990236/objective-c-parsing-xml
-----Never write your own code if you can use a library.

Comment: is there any way to parse this XML into NSDictionary and to use the Key/Value pairs in order to assign the value to labels or Button title etc?

Comment: The simplest way is probly to use XPath to filter all content elements and then retrieve all the attribute nodes...